# MonoTouch.Dialog: AutoHideSearch Doesn't work?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In the `Sample` project which comes with `MonoTouch.Dialog`, if you change the:

```
AutoHideSearch = true;
```

to

```
AutoHideSearch = false:
```

there is no difference, it always hides.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it does. It's designed to "hide" the UISearchBar from being presented to the user when the Dialog is "pushed". When `true` it hides it until the user interacts with the DialogViewController. When `false` when the Dialog is presented it is shown to the user from the beginning.

And when we say hide we really mean it just adjusts the offset:

```
if (AutoHideSearch){
    if (enableSearch){
        if (TableView.ContentOffset.Y < 44)
            TableView.ContentOffset = new PointF (0, 44);
    }
}
```